# Concept of log x and function like fog x, fof x etc.

Tags: functions, logarithms

Might be the question not correct but in functions we come across something like "fof(x)", "fog(x)", etc. So, is "log(x)" meaning something like this? Or is it just a word? And if not what are independent l(x) and g(x)?

Comment: log in log(x) is just a word. Same for cos(x) and a few others.

Comment: $l\circ g\ne \log.$ See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm

Comment: log means the logarithmic function, where $f \circ g$ is the composition of the functions $f$ over $g$.

Answer (score 1):

$l \circ g \neq log$

$\circ$ means the composition of functions: $f \circ g(x) = f(g(x)) $

log stands for logarithm.

Answer (score 0):

The $\circ$ in "$f\circ g$" (what I think is what you mean by $fog$) is not the latter "o", but a little circle symbol (`\circ` in LaTeX) meant to represent the [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition). The notation "$\log$" is an abbreviation for the [logarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm).

This is one reason for why a good typesetting/handwriting is important.

Comment: Thank you for answer!